# Getting Reverse Proxy to work

Tags: reverse-proxy, django

I have a Django web app sharing external ports 80 and 443 with another server. `localhost` works fine without the reverse proxy, but when it is enabled, I run into all kinds of errors.

How to make reverse proxy work properly?

**reverse-proxy.conf**:

```
      # SSL Certificate and other SSL configurations
      SSLProxyEngine on
      ProxyRequests on
      SSLProxyVerify require 
      SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on
      SSLProxyCheckPeerName on
      SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire on
      ProxyPreserveHost on
      RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https

      # Reverse Proxy Configuration
      ProxyPass "/" "https://192.168.1.83/"
      ProxyPassReverse "/" "https://192.168.1.83/"

      # Additional SSL configurations if needed
```

I redirect all `http` to `https` and included the above proxy in my ssl-https conf file. The site runs normally *without* the inclusion (i.e. when `Include .../reverse-proxy.conf` is commented out). When reverse proxy is included, I get:

```
[Thu Jan 18 07:09:39.835368 2024] [ssl:error] [pid 46505:tid 133251102926528] [remote 192.168.1.83:443] AH02039: Certificate Verification: Error (20): unable to get local issuer certificate
[Thu Jan 18 07:09:39.835470 2024] [ssl:error] [pid 46505:tid 133251102926528] [remote 192.168.1.83:443] AH02040: Certificate Verification: Certificate Chain too long (chain has 2 certificates, but maximum allowed are only 1)
[Thu Jan 18 07:09:39.835773 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 46505:tid 133251102926528] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): [client 119.74.38.81:51224] AH01084: pass request body failed to 192.168.1.83:443 (192.168.1.83), referer: https://acupunctureclassique.duckdns.org/
[Thu Jan 18 07:09:39.835832 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 46505:tid 133251102926528] [client 119.74.38.81:51224] AH00898: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server returned by /login/, referer: https://acupunctureclassique.duckdns.org/
[Thu Jan 18 07:09:39.835861 2024] [proxy_http:error] [pid 46505:tid 133251102926528] [client 119.74.38.81:51224] AH01097: pass request body failed to 192.168.1.83:443 (192.168.1.83) from 119.74.38.81 (), referer: https://acupunctureclassique.duckdns.org/
```

On the front end:

```
Proxy Error
The proxy server could not handle the request

Reason: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server

Apache/2.4.58 (Ubuntu) Server at acupunctureclassique.duckdns.org Port 443
```

---

## Update:

`apachectl -S`

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  acupunctureclassique.duckdns.org (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/acu-le-ssl.conf:2)
*:80                   acupunctureclassique.duckdns.org (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/acu.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default 
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

Comment: Please provide your full running config with apachectl -S

Comment: There is also an issue with the certificate the logs say there are two certificates in there

Comment: @Turdie updated with new info.

Comment: I think you saved the reverse proxy in the wrong directory, usually in apache an reverse proxy config is saved as a VirtualHost in /etc/apache2/sites-available and then with a2ensite it creates a symlink to sites-enabled. Usually you don't touch any other config files in other directories. Please also read the docs of apache a bit more.

Comment: I already have 2 virtual hosts set up. One for http, one for https. I just `Include` the above `reverse-proxy.conf` to my https conf file because http traffic would be redirected to https.

Comment: `reverse-proxy.conf` is a partial configuration file that cannot be enabled on its own.

Comment: Does the backend have a valid TLS certificate?

Comment: Yes! The certificate is authorized by let's Encrypt

Comment: No, it isn't. Let's Encrypt will *NOT* issue a certificate for `192.168.1.83`. In fact, noone will, so the only way it can be valid is if you've configured your own PKI.

Comment: I have a valid certificate for a valid public domain name. I am just trying to reverse proxy requests to that domain name to `192.168.1.83` , which is my internal IP address because I have another project that shares the same 80 and 443 ports on my external IP.

Comment: The cert is issued for my public domain name, NOT for `192.168.1.83`. That's why I need the reverse proxy.

Comment: I can serve https *using* the issued cert just fine on my internal network via https://192.168.1.83 *without* the reverse proxy, That's why I say the backend is SSL enabled.

Comment: See my answer. If you visit `https://192.168.1.83` you *have* to click through a warning about incorrect name. The name in the certificate and in the address has to match, that's the *entire* point of TLS. You have to tell apache to go to `https://yourpublicname` for the certificate to be considered valid. And no, you do *not* need a reverse proxy to solve this problem.

Comment: What's the alternative if I don't use reverse proxy? Either server would start complaining I have using the wrong cert and refuse to serve the webpage. I already have a valid cert for each of my domain names. Without reverse proxy, they just keep affecting each other, taking the other cert to be meant for their website.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150946/discussion-between-vidarlo-and-sati).

Answer (score 3):

The actual problem here turned out to be - after discussions in chat - that the user was using nginx to proxy traffic to the same nginx instance, creating a neat redirect loop, which eventually lead to a too large header-error message.

>       ProxyPass "/" "https://192.168.1.83/"

You send your traffic to `https://192.168.1.83`. You claim this is a certificate issued by Let's encrypt, but LE will *never* issue a certificate for `192.168.1.83`, nor will any public CA issue such a certificate. Remember that a *valid* certificate is not enough, it *has* to match the expected name - which in this case is `192.168.1.83`. Your logs are pretty explicit about this as well.

You have a few alternatives:

1. Use HTTP
2. Use a self signed certificate and make Apache trust it using [`SSLProxyCACertificate`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslproxycacertificatefile) directive.
3. Use a valid domain name and acquire a valid certificate for the domain name. The domain name may resolve to `192.168.1.83`, or it may be added to `/etc/hosts`, but Apache *will* match hostname and Common Name (or SAN) in certificate.
4. Disable [verification of name using `SSLProxyCheckPeerName = off`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslproxycheckpeername)
5. Disable verification using [`SSLProxyVerify = none`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslproxyverify), effectively disabling verification. This is more or less equivalent with using http...

Answer (score -2):

To reverse proxy you need to create an virtual host in /etc/apache2/sites-available. Here an example of such an VirtualHost configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourdomain.com
    ServerAlias www.yourdomain.com

    DocumentRoot /path/to/your/django/static/files

    Alias /static/ /path/to/your/django/static/files/
    <Directory /path/to/your/django/static/files>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName yourdomain.com
    ServerAlias www.yourdomain.com

    DocumentRoot /path/to/your/django/static/files

    Alias /static/ /path/to/your/django/static/files/
    <Directory /path/to/your/django/static/files>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/your/ssl/certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/your/ssl/private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/your/ssl/chainfile.pem

    ProxyPass / https://localhost:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:8000/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The https part is optional you can leave that out if you don't need https